# how to log in imessage with applescript on MacOS

Tags: applescript, imessage

I want to login iMessage with applescript and detect if log in successfully.
Also I want to know how to logout the account programmatically.
thanks

Comment: The dictionary of Messages.app has got `log in` and `log out` commands and the `service` class has got a `status` property.

Comment: Yes, I know but how to append the account and password to log in command?

Comment: You need to get or create the `service` (the account) and pass that as the direct parameter to the `log in` command. It's not possible to pass also the password (I guess its possible with GUI scripting).

Comment: can you please help to write a complete demo for me? thanks very much

Comment: do I have to create a keychain first and then when I use 'log in service', the script will automatically use the keychain as account info to  log in?

Comment: No, Messages.app has no access to the keychain. You get a `service` for example `tell application "Messages" to set myService to 1st service whose service type is iMessage`

Comment: Yes, I also did like this. tell application "Messages"
   set myservice to 1st service whose service type is iMessage
   log in myservice
end tell     but how to pass the email and password to the service? when I use log in myservice "email" "pwd" like that it doesn't work